# How do I access variable in sub directory?

Tags: python-2.7

I want to access variable value present in sub-directory

my directory structure is as follows:-

sound/demo/**init**.py

In the **init**.py file **version** variable present i want to access that.

So how do I achieve this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sound/demo/init.py

```
some_var = 'some value'
```

---

sound/script.py

```
execfile('./demo/init.py')
print some_var
```

---

then run script.py from command line:

```
sound ➜ python sample.py
some value
```